# Extracting row in time series in R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I'm trying to extract the rows from a data frame containing the lowest value in a specific column:

```
income = c(2, 3, 5, 5, -15, 2, 1) 
balance = c(15, 17, 20, 25, 30, 15, 17) 
date = as.Date(c("2016/02/11", "2016/02/14", "2017/02/16", "2016/03/01", "2017/03/12", "2016/04/11", "2017/04/24"))
df = data.frame(income, balance, date)
```

Now what I want to get the rows containing the minimum `"balance"` value from each month, so that the outcome would be a data frame looking like this:

```
income balance date
1      2      15 2016-02-11
2      5      25 2016-03-01
3      2      33 2016-04-11
```

I have tryed the aggregate function:

```
bymonth = aggregate(balance~months(date), data=df,FUN=min)
print(bymonth)
```

But this gives me the following output:

```
  months(date) balance
1        April      15
2      Februar      15
3        Marts      25
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do with `dplyr`.  After grouping by `months` of 'date', we `slice` the row which has the `min` 'balance' and remove the 'mth' column using `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(mth = months(date)) %>% 
   slice(which.min(balance)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   select(-mth)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  income balance       date
#   <dbl>   <dbl>     <date>
#1      2      15 2016-04-11
#2      2      15 2016-02-11
#3      5      25 2016-03-01
```

Note that if there are ties for the 'balance', then use `filter(balance == min(balance))` in place of `slice`

---

Or with `ave` from `base R` tp create a logical `vector` and use that to subset the rows of 'df'

```
df[with(df, ave(balance, months(date), FUN = min)==balance),]
#   income balance       date
#1      2      15 2016-02-11
#4      5      25 2016-03-01
#6      2      15 2016-04-11
```